# Get a variable from a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In this code I am wondering how to get the `rect` variable and use it in the `Delete` method as I have tried to do. It currently comes up with an error.

```
from tkinter import *

def createRect(event):
    rect = w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
    return rect

def Start(event):
    print("Single Clicked")
    createRect(event)

def Delete(event):
    i = createRect(event)
    print("Double Clicked")
    w.delete(i.rect)

root = Tk()
w = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()
frame = Button(root, text="delete/make")
frame.bind("<Double-1>", Delete)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", Start)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `rect` is already getting in the `Delete` function. I think you only need to do, `w.delete(i)`... try that!!

Comment: make an argument to pass into the delete function, don't rely on global variables.

Comment: No. Arguments are not possible here since these functions are stateless. I think a global is needed.

Comment: when i just use 'w.delete(i)', there is no errors but the rect var doesn't disappear off the page as it should when 'w.delete(i)' is called.

Comment: What error does it come up with?

Comment: none when I just have `w.delete(i)`

Comment: You must declare `global rect` in `createRect()` and in `Delete()`, and actually delete `rect` in the latter function.

Comment: did you mean like this but it isnt working:

Comment: from tkinter import *

`def createRect(event):
    global rect
    rect = w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
    return rect

def Start(event):
    print("Single Clicked")
    createRect(event)

def Delete(event):
    global rect
    print("Double Clicked")
    w.delete(rect)

root = Tk()
w = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()
frame = Button(root, text="delete/make")
frame.bind("<Double-1>", Delete)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", Start)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would advise against using global variables since you have less control over who can modify them and how. But in this case, your `Start` and `Delete` functions are being called by the mainloop. You can create a container object and use this in your methods.

```
class MyRect:
   def __init__(self):
       self.rect = None
       self.isSet = False
```

Then, inside your tkinter code, you can use it like this:

```
myrect = MyRect()

def Start(event):
    if not myrect.isSet:
        print("Single Clicked")
        myrect.rect = createRect(event)
        myrect.isSet = True

def Delete(event):
    if myrect.isSet:
       print("Double Clicked")
       w.delete(myrect.rect)
       myrect.rect = None
       myrect.isSet = False
```

You can also handle users double clicking or clicking button 1 more times than they should this way.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could add `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` methods that'll control what happens when you modify rect instances when you shouldn't.

Comment: done. But I cant vote it as I haven't got enough reputation yet as I just joined stack overflow.

Comment: @danielmcgregor No worries. Good luck.